# ArcGIS.com and related tables

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-online

I haven't found anything on the ArcMAP forums. Is there any way to represent related tables on  arcGIS.com web maps? I have a geodatabase that has related tables, but so far I am only able to show the feature classes and not the related tables.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question due to lack of extra information, but, have you tried Query Layers? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000027000000 I think that after doing a query layer, you can upload it to ArcGIS.com, isn't it?

Comment: I apologize for lack of information. have a well point file with related tables containing water quality information in a geodatabase. I wanted to know if the related tables can be represented in a ArcGIS.com map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
This is now possible (as of May 2016) according to ESRI's [FAQ article on join and relate support in Online](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012168), though it requires the use of ArcMap:

> Relating tables, via relationship classes, may be performed in ArcMap and then published as a service. Related records may then be displayed in pop-up windows in ArcGIS Online.
>
> Depending on how the relationship class is created, users are able to add or update features and have the related data be updated in the pop-up as well.
>
> However, related tables cannot natively be created in ArcGIS Online, and the in-memory joins or relates are not supported in a feature service.

---

**Original**

ArcGIS Online does not currently support related tables. However, it was [announced at the User Conference on Sep 11, 2014](http://video.esri.com/watch/3838/arcgis-apps) that they are working on this functionality and hope to release in in Q4 2014, or maybe Q1 2015.

They are also working on a closely-related (no pun intended) feature for customizing forms, which presumably will provide a better way to query and update related tables than the current [Javascript tools on Server](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/ed_relatededits.html).

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, ArcGIS Online as a hosting platform does not support related tabled.  However, ArcGIS Server does.

[ArcGIS Idea for promoting this enhancement.](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000brte&returnUrl=/apex/ideaList?c=09a300000004xET&category=ArcGIS%2bExplorer)